# Unable to start activity NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

There are a couple of other questions regarding this on stack but none of them seem to apply to my situation. I hope i am providing the necessary information. The activity does not get to the oncreate method but dies at startActivity()

```
public void showPlaylist(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Playlist.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.www.Swipernoswiping" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.www.Swipernoswiping"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"(Tried removing this line but it didn't help) >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Playlist"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
        at com.overmindserver.www.swipernoswiping.Playlist.<init>(Playlist.java:30)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in `com.overmindserver.www.hivemind.Playlist.<init>(Playlist.java:30)`. You're calling `getApplicationContext()` too early, before `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can give main activity code

try giving activity name instead of , sometime sit causes problem

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Playlist.class);
startActivity(i);
```